# Tuples in Haskell How to access second and third elements

Tags: haskell, tuples

I have the following:

```
type Description = String
type WeeklyHours = Float
type HourlyPay = Float
type JobDB = [(Description, WeeklyHours, HourlyPay)]

weeklyJobPay :: JobDB -> [(Description,Float)]
weeklyJobPay jDB = undefined
```

I need the function weeklyJobPay to multiply weeklyHours by HourlyPay for each tuple in JobDB. How could I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Define an accessor based on pattern matching:

```
sndthd :: (a,b,c) -> (b,c)
sndthd (_,b,c) = (b,c)
```

if you have some other transformation, e.g. hours * pay, a similar function would be:

```
flatten :: JobDB -> (Description, Float)
flatten (d,h,p) = (d, h*p)
```

Note that you should use `Double` rather than `Float`.

Comment: The "`Float` vs `Double`" debate has good arguments for both sides, and `Float` is as often the correct solution as `Double`; in this situation, it is difficult to determine the specific data type that should be used (Maybe `Ratio Int` would be the most suitable).

Comment: For financial calculations, one shouldn't use `Double` either.

Comment: larsmans: that depends, actually. there are some cases where floating point math is appropriate in financial calculations. not for exact arithmetic with dollars and cents, sure, but, e.g., for continuously compounded interest you're going to want to use `exp` and `Double` should be fine...

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern matching and a map:

```
weeklyJobPay :: JobDB -> [(Description,Float)]
weeklyJobPay jDB = map (\(desc, wh, hp) -> (desc, wh * hp)) jDB
```

Although it would be nicer to make a function that calculates weekly pay per job description and then maps over it for a list of them:

```
weeklyDescPay (desc, wh, hp) = (desc, wh * hp)

weeklyJobPay = map weeklyDescPay
```